# Apache Camel: file processing with accented characters

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-camel

We are trying to parse a text file from AWS S3 (sdk2) which has some accented characters like î. We are using camel bindy format @FixedLengthRecord to map the file rows to our DTO, but these accented chars are getting mapped as question mark ?

We are not sure yet about the source file encoding but it shows as ANSI in Notepad++ and also shows the char properly in the input file.

Tried multiple approaches so far like overriding the default charset with different ones US-ASCII, cp1252

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.camel.default.charset", "cp1252");
```

Along with .convertBodyTo(String.class, "UTF-8") in our route definition but none seems to work.

Tried reading the camel documentation https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-component.html  and  similar questions on stackoverflow but didn't find any matching solution yet, any other pointers will be highly appretiated.

Comment: Type chcp  on the command line to find out the "ANSI" code page that Notepad++ used.

Comment: It gives 437, so should we try with cp437?

Comment: Yes, is that a DOS code page maybe? Ah yes, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437

Comment: That didn't work, we are checking if this is due to AWS sdk2 but still any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Finally got a clue in the way camel AWS2S3Endpoint was reading the S3 objects. It was defaulting to UTF-8

```
Reader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s3Object, Charset.forName(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())));
```

This is being fixed in latest 3.6.0 snapshot version as mentioned over camel mailing list. We could test it successfully with the snapshot version along with convertBodyTo(String.class, "ISO-8859-1")  in camel route